# Django style.css is not found

Tags: python, html, django

```
Error :Not Found: /{ % static 'css/style.css' % }
"GET /%7B%20%%20static%20'css/style.css'%20%%20%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2378
```

When I want to link my **style.css** to Django project it throws an error.

**html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Have a Good Day</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{ % static 'css/style.css' % }" > 
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="ok">Great it works</h1>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**settings.py :**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Note : `DEBUG=True`

**Folder structure :**

```
newproject (Folder name)
 - app1(This is my app name)
    -migrations
    -static
        -css
            -style.css
    -templates
    -init__.py
    -admin.py
    -apps.py
    -models.py
    -tests.py
    -urls.py
    -views.py
```

It is only for development . not deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete spaces in tag `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{ % static 'css/style.css' % }" >`

Answer (score 0):

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [....] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Checklist
In production you have to run `python manage.py collectstatic` and add correct folder permission.

How to debug?

Inspect the link in browser and try to change the path manually if you felt anything wrong